# Problems with TXT file encoding in Prolog program on Linux system

Tags: linux, unicode, character-encoding, prolog, swi-prolog

I am working on an university Prolog that consist of a SWI Prolog text analyzer that very simplistically does the following things:

1. **Read a .txt input file that contains some text and put this text into a list of ASCII characters** that I call: ***dataggare.txt***
2. **Do some operations on this original list of ASCII characters and save it in a new file called *System.txt***
3. **Finally compare the new modified *System.txt* file with another file named *oracolo.txt*** (that represents how *System.txt* should be if all operations are completed successfully), **FMeasure value represents how much *System.txt* looks alike as *oracolo.txt*** but this is not important now

The problem appears when I compare my new *System.txt* file with the *oracolo.txt* file and **this problem appear ONLY when I run the program using Linux (if I run it on Windows I have no problem)**

So the problem is that when I execute the following query I have a long series of **warnings** related to the **encoding** of oracolo.txt file

```
[debug]  ?- tagConfronto('dataggare.txt', 'oracolo.txt', FMeasure).
Warning: oracolo.txt:1:422: Illegal UTF-8 continuation
Warning: oracolo.txt:2:77: Illegal UTF-8 continuation
Warning: oracolo.txt:2:129: Illegal UTF-8 continuation
Warning: oracolo.txt:3:31: Illegal UTF-8 continuation
Warning: oracolo.txt:3:71: Illegal UTF-8 continuation
Warning: oracolo.txt:3:199: Illegal UTF-8 start
Warning: oracolo.txt:3:258: Illegal UTF-8 continuation
............
Warning: oracolo.txt:12:222: Illegal UTF-8 continuation
Warning: oracolo.txt:12:563: Illegal UTF-8 continuation
FMeasure = 0.02564102564102564
```

The `tagConfronto/3` predicate compares the *dataggare.txt* file contents with the *oracolo.txt* file and calculates the related `FMeasure` value

As you can see doing this operation finds some problem with the *oracolo.txt* **encoding** that create me many problems because it considerably alters the value of `FMeasure`.

I have this problem only when I run the program on Linux and not when I run it under Windows (in this second case I have no warning and a correct `FMeasure` value)

Some colleagues have told me that maybe I can solve this **re-saving** in some way the files **changing the encoding** (I don't know if I have to save in different way *System.txt* or *oracolo.txt* and I don't know **what kind of encoding I have to use** or if there are different solution)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Unix,

```
?- current_prolog_flag(encoding,X).
X = utf8.
```

while on Windows

```
?- current_prolog_flag(encoding,X).
X = text.
```

Maybe you should set the same value when opening the file, using open/4 - or change globally, using set_prolog_flag/2. To change an already opened stream, use set_stream/2.

I'm not sure `encoding(text)` will be appropriate, see the [documentation page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%272.18%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/widechars.html%27%29%29) for all supported values.

Comment: mmm I have solve in the following simple way: I have create a NEW file named oracle.txt in Linux file system then I have copy the content of the old oracolo.txt file and I have paste it into the new oracle.txt file...then I have use this new version in my tagConfronto/3 predicate and so it work fine...I don't know if it is a clean solution...what do you think about? I will also read the documentation that you pass me

Comment: Your workaround can solve temporarily, but porting data files around platforms will raise again the problem. I found, for instance, that on Unix I needed to set encoding(utf8) when FTPing image files with accents in name. Just an example, I learned 'the hard way' about set_stream/2...